# shopify liquid: plus shipping cost not working

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to multiply the subtotal price by 21% and then add the shipping costs. Because the shipping costs are variable I use the following code.

```
{{ order.subtotal_price | times:1.21 | plus:shipping_method.price | money }}
```

But the shipping costs aren't added.

The example code in the [documentation](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/math-filters) states you can divide a price by `product.compare_at_price` so I thought it should work the same for `shipping_method.price`.

What am I doing wrong? Or is it even possible?

Comment: Did you try [`order.shipping_price`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/order#order-shipping_price)?

Comment: Added it as an answer for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong object. What you're actually looking for is [`order.shipping_price`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/order#order-shipping_price):

```
{{ order.subtotal_price | times:1.21 | plus:order.shipping_price | money }}
```